# Conway's Game of Life-Cells Dying When They're Not Supposed to? (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, debugging, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I am trying to code a very basic version of Conway's Game of Life. My program almost works but the 1's (which represent the alive cells) keep dying even when they have two or three live neighbors. It's strange because the blinker works but when I try the beacon pattern it no longer works.

Here is a wikipedia link that has the patterns I am talking about. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway's_Game_of_Life.

Here is my code:

```
public class GameofLife {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int [][] array = new int [12][12];
    array[8][8]=1;
    array[8][9]=1;
    array[8][7]=1;
    int [][] end = new int [12][12];
    printArray(array);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    int a=0;
    while(a<30){
    for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
    {
        for(int j=1; j<=10; j++)
        {
            int counter = surround(array,i,j);
            if(array[i][j]==1 && counter<2)
            {
                end[i][j]=0;
            }
            if(array[i][j]==1 && counter==2)
            {
                array[i][j]=1;
            }
            if(array[i][j]==1 && counter>4)
            {
                end[i][j]=0;
            }
            if(array[i][j]==0 && counter==3)
            {
                end[i][j]=1;
            }
            if(array[i][j]==1 && counter==3)
            {
                end[i][j]=1;
            }
        }
    }
    printArray(end);    
    a++;
    for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<12; j++)
        {
            array[i][j]=end[i][j];
            end[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    }
```

}

```
    public static int surround(int[][] initial, int i, int j){
    int[][] surrounding = {{initial[i-1][j-1],initial[i-1][j],initial[i-1][j+1]},
            {initial[i][j-1],initial[i][j],initial[i][j+1]},
            {initial[i+1][j-1],initial[i+1][j],initial[i+1][j+1]}};
    int counter = 0;
    for(int a=0; a<=2; a++)
    {
        for(int b=0; b<=2; b++)
        {
            if(surrounding[a][b]==1)
            {
                counter ++;
            }
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
public static void printArray(int[][] input)
{
    for(int x =0; x<input.length; x++)
    {
        for(int y=0; y< input[0].length; y++)
        {
            System.out.print(input[x][y]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

}

Thank you for any help!

Comment: This looks wrong: `if(array[i][j]==1 && counter==2)
            {
                array[i][j]=1;
            }` - shouldn't you be updating the `end` array like in the other checks?

Comment: thank you so much! i have been looking for my mistake for a while

Comment: is there some sort of award or something i can give you on this site

Comment: You can mark Ziyao Wei's answer as correct by clicking the tick beside it. I was too lazy to post an answer, so I don't get anything - but your thanks is plenty :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic in here:

```
for(int a=0; a<=2; a++)
{
    for(int b=0; b<=2; b++)
    {
        if(surrounding[a][b]==1)
        {
            counter ++;
        }
    }
}
```

Is slightly wrong - you don't need to count the cell itself, thus need to skip when `a == 1 && b == 1`.

...and of course, what @Blorgbeard commented :-)